# Apache NIFI: how to solve "waiting for archive cleanup"?

Tags: apache-nifi

I installed NIFI 1.16.1 on Ubuntu and after a couple of weeks started to face following issue: all processes would freeze for some time and Warning would appear on Bulletin board when large amount of FlowFiles was in process:

> Unable to write flowfile content to content repository container
> default due to archive file size contraints; waiting for archive
> cleanup

All of my **nifi.content.repository.** properties were default. I changed *nifi.content.repository.archive.max.retention.period* to 2 days hoping that archive will start cleaning up faster. However, after I restarted NIFI no processesor would execute and I get same warning continuosly. By the way my content_repository folder is just 21 MB in size.

[Content Repository Size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgSsj.png)

[My content repository properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFm8J.png)

How can I solve this issue? Should I just disable archiving or change its properties somehow?

Comment: Same happening to me on 1.23.2